# Why is reading from an istream_iterator assigned to a variable not working?

Tags: c++, iterator, istream-iterator

I wrote the following program that reads in 3 numbers from `std::cin`, and outputs them to `std::cout`, and does this twice:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 
                3, 
                std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 
                3, 
                std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));              
}
```

For an input of `1 2 3 4 5 6`, the program [prints](https://godbolt.org/z/f1j8d1) the expected `1 2 3 4 5 6`.

---

As I found the code a bit verbose, I tried to store the iterators in variables:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    auto ins = std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin);
    auto outs = std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ");
               
    std::copy_n(ins, 3, outs);
    std::copy_n(ins, 3, outs);
}
```

But now for the input `1 2 3 4 5 6`, the program [prints](https://godbolt.org/z/7ojjad) `1 2 3 1 4 5`.

I don't understand the output. What's going on here, and what am I doing wrong?

Also, note that it only matters when I use `ins`. Whether I use `outs` or not doesn't affect the output.

Answer (score 3):

Per [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator):

> std::istream_iterator is a single-pass input iterator that reads successive objects of type T from the std::basic_istream object for which it was constructed, by calling the appropriate operator>>. The actual read operation is performed when the iterator is incremented, not when it is dereferenced. The first object is read when the iterator is constructed. Dereferencing only returns a copy of the most recently read object.

So, when you first create the `ins` variable, it reads `1` from `cin` right away and caches it.

If you look at the declaration of [`copy_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n), the input iterator is passed *by value*, which means it is *copied*.

```cpp
template< class InputIt, class Size, class OutputIt >
OutputIt copy_n( InputIt first, Size count, OutputIt result );
```

Let’s assume, for argument’s sake, that the following implementation of `copy_n()` is being used (check your compiler for actual implementation):

```cpp
template< class InputIt, class Size, class OutputIt>
OutputIt copy_n(InputIt first, Size count, OutputIt result)
{
    if (count > 0) {
        *result++ = *first;
        for (Size i = 1; i < count; ++i) {
            *result++ = *++first;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

When you pass `ins` to `copy_n()`, that cached `1` is copied into the `first` parameter. When `copy_n()` dereferences `first`, it receives the cached `1` and outputs to `result`. Then `copy_n()` increments `first` which reads `2` from `cin` and caches it, then dereferences `first` to receive `2` and output it, then increments `first` which reads `3` from `cin` and caches it, then dereferences `first` to receive `3` and output it, then exits.

When you pass `ins` to `copy_n()` again, the original cached `1` is still in `ins` and is copied into the `first` parameter. When `copy_n()` dereferences `first`, it receives the cached `1` and outputs to `result`. Then `copy_n()` increments `first` which reads `4` from `cin` and caches it, then dereferences `first` to receive `4` and output it, then increments `first` which reads `5` from `cin` and caches it, then dereferences `first` to receive `5` and output it, then exits.

Comment: This is very clear, thanks. I had no idea about this caching behavior. That's what was tripping me up, i.e. once the `1` is read, how could it be read again?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [Defect Report P0738R2](https://wg21.link/P0738R2) you'll see the first read for an `istream_iterator` should be performed by the constructor, so it's reading `1` at the line `auto ins = ...`.

[`copy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) takes its arguments *by value*, so the first invocation doesn't move `main()`s `ins` variable past the `1` it has already read, and that's provided again to the second invocation of `copy_n`.

If you want concision, you could do something like:

```
auto mkins() = [] { return std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin); }

std::copy_n(mkins(), 3, outs);
std::copy_n(mkins(), 3, outs);
```

Comment: Thanks, the fix appears to work. But I'm not clear on the reason for the original code not working. Is the output unspecified?

Comment: @cigien the problem is not in the output. It is because you are reusing the same input iterator object for both `copy_n` calls. Tony’s answer is using 2 input objects, same as your “working” code. See my answer, I explain the problem in more detail.

Comment: @cigien: I thought that was very clear from *"the first read for an `istream_iterator` should be performed by the constructor"*...?  Your code constructs the two `istream_iterator`s before it's finished copying from the first iterator.

Comment: I was confused about the 1 appearing twice in the output. The first value seems to be cached, which I didn't realize from your answer.